# Stepping through an OpenCV Mat with different data types automatically

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, types

This is a general question when stepping through OpenCV Mat in OpenCV >=3.0

Currently, I have a nearly copy-pasted function for each datatype of an OpenCV Mat (32F, 8U, 64F, 16S). That's not great because if I want to change anything, I'd have to change it in all 4 functions.

Let's take, for example, a "max" function for which I step through the pixel elements.

```
uchar* imPtr = (uchar*)A.data;
uchar max=0, dummy;
for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++)
{
    const uchar* Mi = A.ptr<uchar>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++)
    {
        dummy = Mi[j];
        if (dummy > max)
        {
            max = dummy;
        }
    }
}
return max;
```

If we want to write this for 4 datatypes, I'd need to write the same function with (double *), (float *), (int*) and (uchar*). Is there a good way to do something like (auto *)?

Comment: Try c++ template function

Comment: you could write a template function and choose T instead of uchar in your code.

Comment: you could have a look at the open source opencv code for how they implemented for example the minmaxloc function and how they handle pixel types there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `Mat_` class template instead of `Mat`. With `Mat_` you know type at compile time, and it is easy to rewrite your function into function template which is type-safe:

```
template<class T>
T Max(cv::Mat_<T>& A) {
    T* imPtr = (T*)A.data;
    T max = 0, dummy;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
        const T* Mi = A.ptr<T>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++) {
            dummy = Mi[j];
            if (dummy > max)
                max = dummy;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

cv::Mat_<uint8_t> mat1 = (cv::Mat_<uint8_t>(2,2) << 1,2,3,4);
std::cout << (int)Max(mat1) << std::endl; // 4
cv::Mat_<float> mat2 = (cv::Mat_<float>(2, 2) << 4,3,12,11);
std::cout << Max(mat2) << std::endl; // 12
```

---

You could stay with `cv::Mat` but then you have to specify desired type explictly:

```
template<class T>
T Max2(cv::Mat& A) {
    T* imPtr = (T*)A.data;
    T max = 0, dummy;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
        const T* Mi = A.ptr<T>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++) {
            dummy = Mi[j];
            if (dummy > max)
                max = dummy;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

short data[] = { 1,2,3,1 };
cv::Mat mat3(2, 2, CV_16SC1, data);
std::cout << Max2<short>(mat3) << std::endl; // 3
```

but with this version it is easy to make a bug, for example if you specify `T` as `int` when `Mat` was constructed with `CV_32FC1` - find max will truncate all float numbers to `int`, which leads to return improper result.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for! probably going to save 100s-1000s lines of duplicated code now!